# is this possible to share one network adaptor of host between many guests as bridge

Tags: virtualbox, bridge

on my system i installed one network adaptor for each guest which use bridge mode, and no there is no more available slot, is this possible to share one network adaptor between many gusets in bridge mode?

i'm using virtual box

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. With either common option (nat or bridge), you can link as many VMs as you wish (within reason) with a single NIC as a bridge. Having one physical NIC per VM is un-necessary, even if each virtual nic has an IP address on the network the host is on.

Comment: Thats not mentioned anywhere in the original question. I'd guess that each segment MAY need a physical adaptor, but any Vms on that segment would share an adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's precisely what bridge mode does. It creates a bridge the includes the physical interface and the virtual interface(s).